# Count number of non-NaN entries in every column of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, nan

I have a massive DataFrame, and I was wondering if there was a short (one or two liner) way to get a count of non-NaN entries in a DataFrame. I don't want to do this one column at a time as I have close to 1000 columns.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,None),(None,4,None),(5,None,7),(5,None,None)], 
                    columns=['a','b','d'], index = ['A', 'B','C','D'])

    a   b   d
A   1   2 NaN
B NaN   4 NaN
C   5 NaN   7
D   5 NaN NaN
```

Output:

```
a: 3
b: 2
d: 1
```

Comment: df1[df1.notnull()].count()  this seem to have worked

Comment: The extra indexing with `df1.notnull()` is not necessary since `count` ignores null values anyway.

Comment: Unlike `series.value_counts(..., dropna=False)`, there is no option on `df.count()` to directly get NA counts.

Answer (score 209):

The [`count()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) method returns the number of non-`NaN` values in each column:

```
>>> df1.count()
a    3
b    2
d    1
dtype: int64
```

Similarly, `count(axis=1)` returns the number of non-`NaN` values in each row.

Comment: I dont believe that works if the column has strings

Comment: @DISC-O: just tried and it works for me (pandas version 1.2.1). E.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["x", np.nan, "z"]})` then `df.count()` produces the expected value `2`. Do you have an example where this method does not work?

Comment: yes, if you manually create a df and place the np.nan it could work I guess. But that is not how you typically create your columns. One often used way, by me at least is: df['C'] =np.where(df.A>df.B,'some text',np.nan). This turns the np.nan into 'nan' and is no longer recognized as nan.

Comment: I have a column with None values and this doesnt work

Comment: @DISC-O (very late reply, apologies) - in that example you don't end up with any NaN values in the column (you have a column of string values) so the `.count()` method works as intended. Some NumPy methods, especially with strings, don't fit well with pandas and that's one of them so it's better to use pandas methods like `df["C"] = (df.A > df.B).map({True: 'some text', False: np.nan})` instead.

Comment: @West: `.count()` should treat `None` as a null value and count it - happy to debug if you give an example of what you're seeing.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to sum the total count values which are not NAN, one can do;

```
np.sum(df.count())
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you are dealing with empty strings you may want to count them as NA as well :

```
df.replace('', np.nan).count()
```

or if you also want to remove blank strings :

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).count()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use methods [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) / [`notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html#pandas.DataFrame.notnull) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df.notna().sum()
```

Output:

```
a    3
b    2
d    1
dtype: int64
```