# Count the number of non-null values in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, count, null

I have a data frame with some columns, and before doing analysis, I'd like to understand how complete the data frame is. So I want to filter the data frame and count for each column the number of non-null values, possibly returning a dataframe back.

Basically, I am trying to achieve the same result as expressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971075/count-number-of-non-nan-entries-in-every-column-of-dataframe) but using Scala instead of Python.

Say you have:

```scala
val row = Row("x", "y", "z")
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(row(0, 4, 3), row(None, 3, 4), row(None, None, 5))).toDF()
```

How can you summarize the number of non-null values for each column and return a dataframe with the same number of columns and just a single row with the answer?

Comment: thanks very much, I'd appreciate if you can share some snippets to better understand the logic you propose: I can write a UDF to do this, but I don't get how I can write a code that will execute the UDF for each column

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although I like Psidoms answer, often I'm more interested in the fraction of null-values, because just the number of non-null values doesn't tell much...

You can do something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sum,when, count}

df.agg(
   (sum(when($"x".isNotNull,0).otherwise(1))/count("*")).as("x : fraction null"),
   (sum(when($"y".isNotNull,0).otherwise(1))/count("*")).as("y : fraction null"),
   (sum(when($"z".isNotNull,0).otherwise(1))/count("*")).as("z : fraction null")
 ).show()
```

EDIT: `sum(when($"x".isNotNull,0).otherwise(1))` can also just be replaced by `count($"x")` which only counts non-null values. As I find this not obvious, I tend to use the `sum` notation which is more clear

Answer (score 14):

One straight forward option is to use `.describe()` function to get a summary of your data frame, where the count row includes a count of non-null values:

```
df.describe().filter($"summary" === "count").show
+-------+---+---+---+
|summary|  x|  y|  z|
+-------+---+---+---+
|  count|  1|  2|  3|
+-------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: this works only for numeric columns, not for String... right?

Comment: This works for string columns with Spark 2.2.1:  Load with a schema so that we get a string column filled with nothing but nulls: `val xx = spark.read.schema(StructType(Seq(StructField("a", LongType, true), StructField("b", LongType, true), StructField("c", StringType, true), StructField("d", StringType, true)))).json("/tmp/toy.jline")` Then describe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it in Scala 2.11, Spark 2.3.1:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

df.agg(
    count("x").divide(count(lit(1)))
        .as("x: percent non-null")
    // ...copy paste that for columns y and z
).head()
```

`count(*)` counts non-null rows, `count(1)` runs on every row.

If you instead want to count *percent **null** in population*, find the complement of our count-based equation:

```scala
lit(1).minus(
    count("x").divide(count(lit(1)))
    )
    .as("x: percent null")
```

---

It's also worth knowing that you can *cast nullness to an integer, then sum it*.
But it's probably less performant:

```scala
// cast null-ness to an integer
sum(col("x").isNull.cast(IntegerType))
    .divide(count(lit(1)))
    .as("x: percent null")
```

Comment: you can also use `count("*")` instead of `count(lit(1))`, I think this is a bit more readable

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest query:

```
d.filter($"x" !== null ).count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.select(df.columns map count: _*)
```

or

```
df.select(df.columns map count: _*).toDF(df.columns: _*)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 2.3+**
(for string and numeric type columns)

```scala
df.summary("count").show()
+-------+---+---+---+
|summary|  x|  y|  z|
+-------+---+---+---+
|  count|  1|  2|  3|
+-------+---+---+---+
```