# Count the number of missing values in a dataframe Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `dataset` with missing values , I would like to get the number of missing values for each columns. Following is what I did , I got the number of non missing values. How can I use it to get the number of missing values?

```scala
df.describe().filter($"summary" === "count").show
```

```
+-------+---+---+---+
|summary|  x|  y|  z|
+-------+---+---+---+
|  count|  1|  2|  3|
+-------+---+---+---+
```

Any help please to get a `dataframe` in which we'll find columns and number of missing values for each one.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765739/count-the-number-of-non-null-values-in-a-spark-dataframe/41766643#41766643

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could count the missing values by summing the boolean output of the `isNull()` method, after converting it to type integer:

In `Scala`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sum, col}
df.select(df.columns.map(c => sum(col(c).isNull.cast("int")).alias(c)): _*).show
```

In `Python`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,sum
df.select(*(sum(col(c).isNull().cast("int")).alias(c) for c in df.columns)).show()
```

Alternatively, you could also use the output of `df.describe().filter($"summary" === "count")`, and subtract the number in each cell by the number of rows in the data:

In `Scala`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit,

val rows = df.count()
val summary = df.describe().filter($"summary" === "count")
summary.select(df.columns.map(c =>(lit(rows) - col(c)).alias(c)): _*).show
```

In `Python`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

rows = df.count()
summary = df.describe().filter(col("summary") == "count")
summary.select(*((lit(rows)-col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns)).show()
```

Comment: thanks for your help .it worked.But is there an alternative waythat takes less time.because it took to much time for large data

Comment: @mtoto The describe() function computes all other operations, hence can take more time, use: df.summary("count") to limit computations only for counting.
No need to use: df.describe().filter(col("summary") == "count")

Comment: That's very useful thanks, how would I add multiple metrics to the output? i.e. a row for isNull and a row for value=X for each Column

Answer (score 2):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnull, when, count, col
nacounts = df.select([count(when(isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).toPandas()
nacounts
```

Comment: it would be a more complete answer if you can provide some explanation of what the code is doing and also if you can format the code properly, please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for details on how to format the code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in df.columns:
  print(i,df.count()-(df.na.drop(subset=i).count()))
```